# Some concurrency-design in java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, runnable, java-threads

I need to retrieve a huge picture from a server but the server can't do that because the image is too big. I can give "coordinates" so that I can retrieve small parts of that picture. So I split the picture in to 100 tiles and than append 10 tiles to a row and than I append each row. That works well when I do it sequentially. Right now I download 10 tiles -> append them to a row -> download next 10 tiles -> append them to a row -> append the second row to the first one -> download next 10 tiles etc.(simplified):

```
public static void downloadWholeImage(){
   int xcoord=0;
   int ycoord=0;
   //outer loop for each row
   for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
      //all tiles of a row are stored here
      BufferedImage[] tilesForRow = new BufferedImage[10];
      //inner loop for each tile of a row
      for(int j = 0; j<10; j++){
         //downloads the image
         BufferedImage tile = downloadImage(xcoord,ycoord);
         //removes all black pixels of the image
         BufferedImage[j] = removeBlackColor(tile);
         //increments xcoord so the next tile
         xcoord++;
      }
      //each row gets appended on top of the first row
      if(i==0){
         BufferedImage firstRow = appendTilesToRow(tilesForRow)
      } else{
         BufferedImage actualRow = appendTilesToRow(tilesForRow)
      }

      firstRow = appendActualToFirst(firstRow, actualRow); 
      //incrementing ycoord for next tile
      ycoord++;
   }
   writeImage(path,firstRow);
}
```

But since the rows are really big it takes very long to append them to each other. While they are being appended, I thought that I could create a thred that downloads the other tiles. And here is the problem. I am not used to program concurrently. I know how it is done technically (implement Runnable etc.) but how should I design it? I had the Idea to run `downloadImage(xcoord, ycoord)` in another thread but that leads to the question where to put the `removeBlackColor(tile)` . Also in the thread or after the thread is finished?.. And who should wait for what (with join) ? I hope it was not that confusing. Please let me know if you need more clarification somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me you need to still download the rows sequentially and within each row ensure all 10 tiles are download before moving onto the next row.

Take a look at `java.util.concurrent` package, specifically the [`CountDownLatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html).

heres a code snippete. **Note:** it may not compile correclty but gives an idea.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    CountDownLatch countLatch = new CountDownLatch(10);
    ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    ArrayList<SampleImageDownload> list = new ArrayList<SampleImageDownload>();
    int row =1;

    while (row <=10) {
        int tileno = 1;
        while(tileno <=10) {
         SampleImageDownload sample = new SampleImageDownload(countLatch, tileno);
         list.add(sample);
         threadPool.submit(sample); 
         tileno++;

        } 
            row++;
            countLatch.await(); // wait for all 10 tiles to download.
        //apendline
    }




}


class SampleImageDownload implements Runnable {

    int tileno;
    private CountDownLatch countLatch = null;
    BufferedImage tile = null;


    public SampleImageDownload(CountDownLatch countLatch, int tileno) {
        super();
        this.countLatch = countLatch;
        this.tileno = tileno;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {

        // download and removeBlacktile
        // tile is ready
        countLatch.countDown();

    }

}
```

Comment: I am not sure wether I understood that but: You are using a thread but only one at a time? So there is no concurrency and it would take as much as without a thread (like in my question above) or?

Comment: The `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);` creates a thread pool and we submit each tile download to this pool.And 10 threads run simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it something like this: create a new thread for every download operation, where the download occurs in the run() method.  Each thread then waits for the next download to complete with join() and appends the tile.

A similar approach can be used to download and append each row.

```
public class Download extends Thread {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Download[] download = new Download[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            download[i] = (new Download(i));
            download[i].start();
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            (download[i]).join();
            append(i);
        }
    }
    int val;
    Download(int val) {
        this.val = val;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
            System.out.println("Downloading tile " + val);
    }
```

**EDIT**

If you prefer to implement Runnable, the syntax goes like

```
public class Download implements Runnable {
...
        Thread[] download = new Thread[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            download[i] = new Thread(new Download(i));
```

This works in exactly the same way as the first example, so the choice of extending Thread or implementing Runnable is a matter of taste.

Comment: cool, is that also going to work with `implements runnable` instead of `extends thread`?
And the second for-loop is getting started when the first iteration of the first loop is finished right?

Comment: Yes, `implements Runnable` works the same way with a slightly different syntax.  The first loop schedules the 10 threads, but does not wait for them to start. The main() method will immediately go to the second loop and wait for the downloads to complete.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to download the other tiles asynchronous, while your tile are appending.

For that it looks like your answer can be found here:
[How does one implement a truly asynchronous java thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676687/how-does-one-implement-a-truly-asynchronous-java-thread)

Notice: You do not need to wait. Just let one process finish asynchronous, while another is running.

EDIT: You could also use synchronized-blocks to define, that after every successful download the specific appending should be executed.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possibilities would be to create the main thread which would run N downloading threads. Each download thread would get the tile from server and then it could swap the fragment of big picture with the tile. As for swapping it probably could be done at the same time by many threads as long as each one operates on its own portion of the big picture so they won't "collide". Think of an array where one thread works with the indexes 0 to X and the other X+1 to the end of an array. For it to work you have to know the size of the  big picture beforehand and initialize it. But I think you already do. The main thread would just wait for all small threads to end which would mean the the job is done.

Comment: thanks for the answer but what do yo mean by 'swap the fragment of big picture with the tile'?